# Product page details tabs to lightbox

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

in my woocomere product page there is tabs of a product to display different information (description, etc). But i wish to be able to in a specific tab turn in a ligthbox popup that shows text or a image. Is there any plugin available in wordpress for it?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code in function.php to show tab content in light box. Might be you will have to customize more but basic structure i am sharing with you.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs','outputTabTitle');

add_action( 'woocommerce_product_write_panels','outputTabEditContent');

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs','productTab');
```

function outputTabTitle ()

```
{

    ?>

    <li class="custom_tab">

        <a href="#custom-tab" class="lightbox">Additional Information</a>

    </li>

    <?php
}

function outputTabEditContent ()

{
    global $woocommerce, $post;

    echo '<div id="custom-tab" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">';

    /************Please put you lightbox  text and image here. 

    echo '</div>';
}

function productTab ( $tabs )

{
    $tabs['custom-tab'] = array(

        'title'     => __( 'Additional Information', 'woocommerce' ),

        'priority'  => 50,

        'callback'  => 'outputTabEditContent'
    );

    return $tabs;
}
```